# Configuration of IIS for Intranet Application ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I want to host an ASP.NET MVC project as an intranet webapp. Currently I'm struggling with the configuration of the IIS. Finally the webapp should use the information of the logon (windows) user and check it through the AD. Does this the IIS imiplict or do I need some extra code in my project?

My current configuration:
I have enabled **only** Windows Authentication in my ASP.NET project.
In the IIS I also **only** enabled Windows Authentication in the Authentication option of the hosted site. My .NET Authoritzation Rules:

Allow All Users Inherited & Allow mydomain\myuser GET,POST Local

I also granted the IIS Application pool rights for the respective folder in the directory (

Within these settings I also get stucked while get onto the page. The first weird thing is, that the site ask for my username and password (Why it doesn't take the information of the logon user?). The second weird thing is (that is - I think - in correlation to the first thing) doesn't accept my correct! credentials.

For me it seems like the server cannot check the credentials or more basically - the server doesn't know where he have to check it.

**/EDIT1/** here my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: post up your web config please

Comment: try putting <authorization> <deny users="?"/> </authorization> under the authentication mode

Comment: doesn't worked. may I specify anything in the applicationhost.config of the server?

For me it really seems like, that he can't verify credentials against an AD Server or kind of this... But really don't where to look

Comment: In IIS then: Check under Authentication, then Windows Authentication highlight it, click providers make sure negotiate is top of the list, it that doesnt work, change them around NTLM at the top

Comment: NTLM at the top works! Thanks!! I will post my whole configuration later

Comment: No Problem, glad it works now

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a browser setting whether the credentials should be silently supplied without asking the user.

Look at the link below, it is about something else but it also has the steps to configure the browser.
https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM

Try using credentials of a user account on the server itself to see if that works. If the Active Directory service is working, the server should be able to authenticate the users. You might also want to try removing the authorization for a particular domain/user first and add that later if you are able to authenticate.

Keep in mind that you'll also have to disable anonymous authentication.

Comment: I tried the logon with a local user - but it ends again in a new request of credentials..